# How can I check if a certain function could be indirectly called by another certain function?

Tags: c, static-analysis

Assuming that in a project written by C, there is a function named `A` and a function named `B`.

**How can I verify if the function A could be in the call tree of function B? Just like B->C->D->...->A** .

This question came when I was thinking about which `libvirt` API may invoke the qemu qmp "query-block". Since qmp "query-block" is only called by function `qemuMonitorJSONQueryBlock`. So this specific question becomes: How can I find which `libvirt` API may invoke `qemuMonitorJSONQueryBlock`?

I think dynamic analysis is hard to answer that question because lots of tests are required. It should be a question of static analysis. But I could find proper tools or methods to solve it. At last I summarize the question as the first paragraph.

Comment: First step could be [GNU cflow](https://www.gnu.org/software/cflow/manual/cflow.html#Intro). (I saw it mentioned recently in a similar question though I haven't heard about it before nor I have any experience.) Second step could be to analyze the output graph (Is there a path from B to A?) with the usual algorithms of graph theory (if it's not even a feature of cflow).

Answer (score 1):

You can try [CppDepend](https://www.cppdepend.com) and its code query language to create some advanced queries about the dependencies, In you case you can use a query like this one

```
    from m in Methods 
let depth0 = m.DepthOfIsUsedBy("__Globals.B()")
where depth0  >= 0 && m.SimpleName=="A" orderby depth0 
select new { m, depth0 }
```

[image]

Comment: It looks good. And I am waiting the free trial mail with download link. BTW, do you know any **open source** solutions to this question?

Answer (score 0):

You can use GNU cflow utility which analyzes a collection of source files written in C programming language and outputs a graph charting dependencies between various functions

Comment: The result of cflow is not well-formated. I think it is a little hard to get the full call trace of functions.

Answer (score 0):

> I think dynamic analysis is hard to answer that question because lots of tests are required. It should be a question of static analysis. But I could find proper tools or methods to solve it. At last I summarize the question as the first paragraph.

That's true, basically because you can call functions that you have never linked in your program.  with the `dlopen(3)` function and friends, you can dynamically link to your program a completely unknown function and be able to call it.  There's no way to check if the pointer to a function is actually storing a valid pointer and to see if, as a result, it will be called or not (or if it is in the call graph of some initial function)

Answer (score 0):

I find [cscope](http://cscope.sourceforge.net/) can help solve the question. It is a
is a **developer's tool for browsing source code**. It can get the caller of a function by following:
1. Change to the **source code directory**, then generate the **cscope database file** named *cscope.out*

```sh
cd libvirt
cscope -bR
```

2. Find the **callers** of **func1** by cscope:
   `cscope -d -f cscope.out -L3 func1`, then **2nd column** is the callers of this function. For example:

```
cscope -d -f./cscope.out -L3 qemuMigrationDstPrepareDirect
```

The result:

```
src/qemu/qemu_driver.c ATTRIBUTE_NONNULL 12487 ret = qemuMigrationDstPrepareDirect(driver, dconn,
src/qemu/qemu_driver.c qemuDomainMigratePrepare2 12487 ret = qemuMigrationDstPrepareDirect(driver, dconn,
src/qemu/qemu_driver.c qemuDomainMigratePrepare3 12722 ret = qemuMigrationDstPrepareDirect(driver, dconn,
src/qemu/qemu_driver.c qemuDomainMigratePrepare3Params 12809 ret = qemuMigrationDstPrepareDirect(driver, dconn,
```

Note that: cscope will mistakenly regard function attribute declarement **ATTRIBUTE_*** as callers. We should skip them.

Then recursively find the caller of the a function. At last select the target **B->...->A** call trace.

Answer (score 0):

**doxygen** can generate call graphs and caller graphs. If you configure it for an unlimited number of calls in a graph, you will be able to get the information you need.